# How Floyd Warshall algorithm works for N=500 within 1 second?

Tags: time-complexity, graph-theory, floyd-warshall

I am learning graph theory, and I found a problem Shortest Route II on CSES website.
https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1672/ is the problem.
I found the problem could be solved using Floyd Warshall Algorithm and the time complexity for the algorithm is **O(n^3)**.
I am confused because here the constraints are **N<=500, Time limit: 1s**, so when N=500 the computations should be 500^3 = 125,000,000 and keeping in mind that in **1 second**, **10^8** computations are performed, therefore it should at least take 1.25 seconds causing TLE, but the solution gets accepted. I want to learn what I am doing wrong in my calculations or understanding.

Comment: Keep in mind that the big O notation is worst case. Also, any scalar values are ignored complexity-wise (I.E O(2 * n^2) == O(n^2) == O(0.1 * n^2)). I don't know if that is the solution to your problem though.

Comment: @Schottky The algorithm uses 3 nested loops and each loop iterates from 1 to N, so it results in O(n^3) time complexity and I am pretty sure about it.

Comment: Your problem is that you assume `10^8 computations are performed`. Have you actually run the code and counted the computations?

Comment: @GuyCoder  I checked running a specific test case which on the CSES website took **0.97 seconds** (N = 500 in this test case) and on my computer, it takes **1277ms or 1.277 seconds** which is close enough to my estimated calculation. Note: I use java.

Comment: The comparison is done 500^3 times ignoring the fact the graph is connected or not.
The logic @GuyCoder : 
Assuming **10^8** computations cost **1 second.**
So let's say for  **10^9** computations, we can rewrite as, 
**10 x 10^8** computations which results **10 X 1 seconds.**
Similarly, **125,000,000** is equal to **1.25 X 10^8** which results in **1.25 X 1 seconds.** I found many tutorials where they just did this problem with the Floyd-Warshall algorithm and made me think why the solution is getting accepted when on my computer it takes an estimated time of 1.27 s.

Comment: Why do you think that the computer behind _the CSES website_ couldn't do more _computations_ per _second_ than your _computer_?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.